# VBA Excel 2010 Editor capitalizes property name and it cannot be accessed

Tags: vba, excel

As a response to a POST, the server returns very simple JSON object that can indicate success or failure of the upload.

The JSON object can be either {config_version:N} to indicate success or {exception:Reason} to indicate failure.

I process the response in the following manner:

```
json = objHTTP.responseText
Set sc = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
sc.Language = "JScript"
Set o = sc.Eval("(" + json + ")")

On Error GoTo Exception:
' try to use config_version property
Util.SetConfigData "version", o.config_version
Exit Function

Exception:
If o.Exception = "config_not_valid" Then
   ' one kind of exception - do accordingly
Else
   ' another kind of exception
End If
```

The problem that I am facing is that the VBA Excel 2010 editor is capitalizing `o.exception` to `o.Exception`! In the `Watch` window I see the property `exception` but cannot access it. How can I force the Editor to stop capitalizing the property name? Is there other syntax for accessing properties in VBA?

**EDIT**: To better illustrate what is happening here are two screen shots.

[image]

As you can see, the `o` has a property called `exception`. When trying to access it with `o.Exception` it triggers the 438 error.

[image]

Since I have control over the backend, I changed the response to return `{Exception:whatever}` (cannot do it permanently). Now VBA has no problem picking the property.

How is this possible if the VBA compiler is case-insensitive as suggested by Jean-François Corbett?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is wierd.  I can get the lower-case "e" to stick in Tester(), but if I change the declaration of "exception" in Test2() to "Exception", then *the VBE automatically changes changes any instances in Tester() to "Exception"*. Changing back to "exception" has the reverse effect.

Basically you need to make sure you're not using "Exception" *anywhere* else in your project.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim sc, o

    Set sc = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
    sc.Language = "JScript"
    Set o = sc.Eval("({exception:'blahblah'})")

    Debug.Print o.exception 'prints blahblah

End Sub


Sub Test2()
    Dim exception As String
    exception = "blah"
End Sub
```

EDIT:

If you're still stuck then you can try it this way, leaving your parsed JSON object in the script control instance:

```
Set sc = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
sc.Language = "JScript"

sc.Eval "var o = eval({exception:'blahblah',message:'oops'})"

Debug.Print sc.Eval("o.exception")     'prints blahblah
Debug.Print sc.Eval("o['exception']")  'same thing...

Debug.Print sc.Eval("o.message")       'prints oops
```

Comment: This works. When I `Dim` a variable `exception` in the same function, the editor doesn't capitalize the `e` anymore. This solves my problem. Thanks for that. But why if the compiler is case insensitive as suggested by Jean-François Corbett it complains about missing property?

Comment: Although VBA isn't case-sensitive, it may be that the property names of the javascript object returned from the script control *are* case-sensitive: that would kind of make sense with javascript itself being a case-sensitive language.

Comment: Guess that is the reason. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Change the label `Exception:` to `except:`

```
except:
If o.exception = config_not_valid Then
```

Also, change the line of code where it would've used `goto Exception` to `goto except`.

Comment: That's the thing, whenever I write `o.exception`, the editor changes it to `o.Exception`

Comment: In that case, change the label `Exception:` to some other name (such as `error:`). After that, rewrite the line `If o.exception = config_not_valid Then`. What type of variable `o` is? Does it have `exception` property? How is it spelled?

Comment: It still continues to capitalize the `e`.

Comment: `o` is not `Dim`ed. Thus I don't know what is its type, guess `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

The VBA compiler is case-insensitive, so there is *absolutely no difference* between `o.exception` and `o.Exception` as far as VBA is concerned. The capitalization is not the reason you cannot access the `exception` property. (*EDIT: This last sentence is not true! See @Tim Williams' answer. I stand corrected.*)

However, you will have to clarify what you mean by "cannot access". What is `config_not_valid`? (My hunch is, it's an enum from an external library that has not been properly referenced through early binding.)

Declaring all of your variables using `Dim` with the proper, specific type may help (and you should always do this anyway). Setting references (Tools > References) to allow early binding may also help. It's hard to give better advice unless you give us more detail about your problem.

That being said, if, *for cosmetic purposes only*, you want to stop the capitalization from happening in the VBA editor, then have a look at @Tim Williams' and @shahkalpesh's answers. The VBA editor's capitalization scheme can sometimes seem quirky. Declaring all of your variables using `Dim` will make some of these quirks go away -- but that's really the least reason why you should `Dim` *everything*, *always*.

Comment: Please, look at the edit of the question. I placed screen shots to show what is happening. Please, note also that `config_not_valid` is actually a string. My bad.