# VBA Access 2016 IDE capitalising object property

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm working with a block of code in VBA (Access 2016) to get the status of a MailChimp contact via their API:

```
With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    .Open Request, APIUrl & APIString & Criteria, False
    .setrequestheader "Authorization", "Basic " & APIAuth
    .send
    APIResponse = .responsetext
    If InStr(APIResponse, "{""exact_matches"":{""members"":[]") > 0 Then
        MailExist = False
        Else
        MailExist = True
        Set JSONControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
        JSONControl.language = "Jscript"
        APIString = "XXXXXXX"
        .Open Request, APIUrl & APIString & Criteria, False
        .setrequestheader "Authorization", "Basic " & APIAuth
        .send
        Set Subber = JSONControl.Eval("(" + .responsetext + ")")
        If Subber.status = "subscribed" Then
            MailSub = True
            Else
            MailSub = False
        End If
    End If
End With
```

Towards the end I use the 'Subber' object to see if the contact is subscribed or not

**If Subber.status = "subscribed" Then**

This has been working fine until recently, when the 'status' Property is suddenly being capitalised by the IDE, causing it to error out with an 'Object does not support this property or method' message.

I've done some digging and found a similar problem with a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835553/vba-excel-2010-editor-capitalizes-property-name-and-it-cannot-be-accessed), but after following the solutions the 'status' is still being capitalised. I've tried checking through the whole project for the word 'Status' with no results, and none of the controls on my forms use it either. I did have a table field with the name 'Status' but I've since renamed that so it shouldn't affect it, and I've also tried setting a public variable called 'status'. This worked to set the property back to all lowercase, but once the code is triggered the property goes back to 'Status', along with the variable name. I'm now stuck and can't figure out why the capitalisation occurs!

Comment: As the link mentions, it's primarily a cosmetic issue. So this is probably only the symptom on something else (worse) that is going on elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Can you use [CallByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function) ?

Comment: @QHarr, CallByName has done the trick. Thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome. I will post below with a reference for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [CallByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function)

The `CallByName` function is used to get or set a property, or invoke a method at run time using a string name. This means you can pass in your required property as an argument without this capitalisation. Use vbGet to retrieve value.